# Data modelling for dynamic grouping of rows in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have a feed of game events with a schema like;

```
{
   "gameId": text,
   "playerId": text,
   "eventId": text,
   "ts": bigint,
   "metrics": map<text,double>,
   "dimensions": map<text, text>
}
```

An example event might look like this;

```
{
   "gameId": "eb9dafbf-d81a-4d2a-b19b-f9149ee90520",
   "playerId": "738a90ef-f09a-459b-91af-452f25f48c8d",
   "eventId": "ebec5e8c-118b-42a2-aa87-2ecdbc42aa58",
   "ts": 1677685878,
   "metrics": {
      "moves": 11.0
      "xp": 100.0,
      "hp": 431.0
   },
   "dimensions": {
      "characterId": "5fdf53f0-ad6d-43fc-a422-8a679277f4df",
      "serverId": "d07e57c2-166a-4119-8d4b-cc0778d10069",
      "tournamentId": "40e53993-46b0-42d8-be5a-4fd199a31ad3"
   }
}
```

The table primary key would likely be `gameId, playerId, day, (ts, eventId)`. Day being `YYYY-mm-DD` extracted from the ts value to keep the partition sizes low and allow for performant inserts.

I have a requirement to query these events by a dynamic set of `dimensions`, essentially allocating all events into groupings based on the value of the provided dimension keys.

In a relational world, Pseudo-SQL for doing so might look something like;

```
WITH 
segments(seg_ordinal, seg_character, seg_tournament) AS (
  VALUES (1, 'char_1', 'tourn_1'), (2, 'char_1', null), (3, null, 'tourn_1'), (4, null, null)
),
exploded(gameId, playerId, eventId, dimensions, seg_ordinal, seg_character, seg_tournament) AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM events e, segments s
    WHERE (e.dimensions.characterId = s.seg_character OR s.seg_character IS null)
    AND   (e.dimensions.tournamentId = s.seg_tournament OR s.seg_tournament IS null)
)
SELECT e1.seg_ordinal AS Segment_Ordinal, SUM(e1.metrics.xp) AS AggregatedResult
FROM exploded e1
LEFT JOIN exploded e2 ON e1.eventId = e2.eventId AND e2.seg_ordinal < e1.seg_ordinal
WHERE e2.eventId IS NULL
GROUP BY e1.seg_ordinal
ORDER BY e1.seg_ordinal
```

As the dimension keys (in this example `characterId` and `tournamentId`), and the metric being aggregated (in this example `SUM(xp)`), are dynamic, and not always known ahead of query time, it's difficult to flatten them into the schema suitable for a Cassandra table.

A secondary index on the the dimensions map entries would allow me to query by any dimension, if I need to query by more than one dimension at a time, as in the provided example, I need to allow filtering on the query. This is likely OK as all partition keys would be provided so all filtering will still be scoped to a single Cassandra partition, and secondary indexes are generally troublesome when a query needs to scan across multiple partitions, however this still doesn't solve for the dynamic nature of the "segment" requirement.

How should I best model this suitable for querying in Cassandra?

Answer (score 1):

You have a good understanding of the Cassandra data modeling rules. First a couple of ideas that worth mentionning to maybe improve the design:

**Improvements**

- use snake case in cassandra column names
- `gameId`, `playerId` could be of `uuid` type (based on the way they are formatted in your example)
- `ts` and `eventid` can be a single field of type `timeuuid` (with a precision of 100ns) and easy to insert with `now()`
- Adding columns in a Cassandra table is almost free as it will not add any null value if empty. So why not have each dimension as a proper column? Having all dimension in a Map you might be tempting to have frozen values and that would create quite some tombstones if you edit them frequently.
- if, in your where clause you spot a specific partition (providing the 3 parts) it is not useful to create a secondary index. You can simply there (and only there) use the ALLOW FILTERING keyword.

**A first proposition would be :**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS games (
  game_id      uuid,
  player_id    uuid,
  day_yyymmdd  text,
  event_id     timeuuid,
  metrics      map<text,double>,
  dim_character_id  uuid,
  dim_server_id     uuid,
  dim_tournament_id uuid,
  PRIMARY KEY((game_id, player_id, day_yyymmdd), event_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (event_id desc);
```

Now regarding the dynamic query part:

Even if you duplicate the data in multiple tables, based on different queries, the fact that it is totally dynamic and the aggregation piece makes it a dead-end.

**What you are supposed to do ?**

Query the whole partition and do the aggregation at the code level